# Reply to first unique comment without page refresh

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Good day everyone,

I have the following html code

```
<form method="post" action="blog_comment_post.php" id="post_blog_comment">
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $postid; ?>" name="blogid" id="blogid"/>
<textarea name="blog_comment" class="blog_comment_form" id="blog_comment" placeholder="Join the discussion"></textarea>
</form>
```

and the following javascript coding to actually post the comment to a php file and to have the comment displayed on the page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#post_blog_comment").keypress(function(evt) {
        if(evt.which == 13) {
            var commentform = $("#post_blog_comment");
            var blogid = $("#blogid").val();
            var comment = $("#blog_comment").val();
            //$.post("blog_comment_post.php", { blogid: blogid, comment: comment},
            //function(data) {

            var newmedia =`<div class="blog_comm_hold">
                <div class="user_comment_photo1">
               <img src='<?php echo $avatar; ?>' width='100%' height='100%' title='commenting as <?php echo $name; ?>'/>
                </div>
                <div class="blog_comment_">
                    <div class="blog_com_text">
                    ${comment}
                    </div>
                    </div>
                <br>
                <div class="reply_to_comm">
                     Reply
                     </div>
                    </div>`;

            commentform.after(newmedia);
            $('#post_blog_comment')[0].reset();
            //});
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

And the following html code which represents a form to actually reply to the posted comment

```
<form action="blog_comment_post.php" method="post" id="blog_comment_subform">
<div class="blog_subform_hold">
<div class="user_subcomment_photo">
    <img src='<?php echo $avatar; ?>' width='100%' height='100%' title='commenting as <?php echo $name; ?>'/>
</div>
<textarea placeholder="Reply to Comment" class="blog_comment_subform" name="blog_comment_sub" id="blog_comment_sub"></textarea>
</div>
</form>
```

And finally, the javscript coding to actually post the reply comment and have that comment be displayed under the main comment that I want to reply to.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#blog_comment_subform").keypress(function(evt) {
        if(evt.which == 13) {
            var commentsub_form = $("#blog_comment_subform");
            var blog_subcmt = $("#blog_comment_sub").val();
            var commentid = 0;
            if(commentsub_form.parents(".blog_comm_hold").length > 0) {
                commentid = commentsub_form.closest(".blog_comm_hold").attr("data-Id");
            }
            console.log(commentid);
            console.log(blog_subcmt);

//$.post("blog_comment_post.php", { commentid: commentid, blog_subcmt: blog_subcmt},
//function(data) {
            var newsubmedia =`<div class="blog_subcomm_hold">
                <div class="user_subcomment_photo1">
               <img src='<?php echo $avatar; ?>' width='100%' height='100%' title='commenting as <?php echo $name; ?>'/>
                </div>
                <div class="blog_subcomment_">
                    <div class="blog_com_text">
                    ${blog_subcmt}
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>`;

            commentsub_form.after(newsubmedia);
            $('#blog_comment_subform')[0].reset();
  //          });
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

All of the above codes are working fine but I still have a sort of an issue that I thought about very recently.

I have a php file that generates all comments from the database and each comment having their own php id. As can be seen in the following code structure below,

```
<div class="blog_comm_hold" data-Id="<?php echo $cmt_id; ?>">
<div class="user_comment_photo1">
    <?php echo "
    <img src='$profile_pic2' width='100%' height='100%' title='commented as $name'>
    "; ?>
</div>
<div class="blog_comment_">
    <div class="blog_com_text">
        <?php echo $comment; ?>
    </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="reply_to_comm">
    Reply
</div>
    </div>
```

For each comment, it has its own unique id and this is generated from the database based on the auto increment numbering basis. I named the variable as $cmt_id. The above code is just the html output of the fetched comments  from the database. Like i said above, the current configuration works well now.

However, here is my real problem that I am looking for a solution towards. 
If the page has zero comments on it, and I decided to post my first comment. Based on the javacript above, the comment will be posted to the php file and then be displayed on the screen. 
Now, what if i decided to reply to that comment immediately (I have not refreshed the page so that the comment won't be fetched from the database), based on the coding above, you will notice that the reply comment would be posted to the comment that I am interested to reply to. Again, this would be determined by the $cmt_id variable i set above for each comment. 
Because i did not refresh the page, there is no value set for the $cmt_id variable i assume. As such, I don't know which comment i am replying to since no value found for $cmt_id. How do i work my way around this.

I know that if i decided to refresh the page, that the value would be fetched form the variable $cmt_id from the database. But I don't want to refresh the page. I want to be able to reply to that comment instantly and that the reply comment gets posted to the php file with the correct comment id value that was supposed to be in variable $cmt_id.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why not return the id when posting the comment and dynamically add it to the page when the ajax call returns?

Comment: how do i return it?